# How do I make my enemy die if the passenger dies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I'm making one of those "Only One Command" things but for one of the specific enemies im trying to make has a feature where if you hit his head he'll die. More specifically, there is a slime riding him which goes over his head and i am trying to make it so if the slime dies, the zombie will die and the mini-slimes will spawn in and attack the player but everything i've tried only works for 1.12 and has no effect on 1.14-1.15 (the version im using) please someone help.

Comment: What did you try? It's much easier to just translate 1.12 commands to 1.13+ commands than to figure out what you want and re-invent the entire system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you just want e.g. every entity tagged "`exampleTag`" to die when it has no passengers, simply do this:

```
/execute as @e[tag=exampleTag] unless data entity @s Passengers run kill @s
```

When the last passenger dies or dismounts, Minecraft not only empties the `Passengers` tag, but deleted it. That way you can simply check for the existence of that NBT tag. Even if it didn't get deleted, you could just check for `Passengers[0]` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was very confused with that specific line i needed for the enemy

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can indicate that and mark your question as "solved" by clicking the checkmark icon below the vote buttons.